# From nothing to emailjs to emailjs-com

Tags: angular

My Angular Application was using nothing, then I installed npm install emailjs, and afterwards i changed to emailjs-com (npm install emailjs-com), when I use ng build/serve now, I get the following error:

**ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'emailjs'.**

I uninstalled emailjs with npm uninstall emailjs, I deleted node_modules and did an npm install, still no success.

Comment: Check your package.json file and ensure the `emailjs` package is not listed there, but emailjs-com is. Then try deleting node_modules *and* package-lock.json. Then try again with `npm install`.

Comment: I tried it, i found a reference to emailjs in package.json, afterwards I performed the steps you recommended, but still the same result

Comment: Is something in your code somewhere trying to import or use `emailjs`?

Comment: Can you try clearing your `npm cache clean -f`?

Comment: cache clean did not help. i checked all components that are using emailjs-com all components are using emailjs-com and the reference is named email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow emailjs was referenced in tsconfig.app.json under types, removing this soleved the problem.